# fetch value from another dataframe based on a lookup value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABCD'), 'Set':list('ZZXY')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABCDEF'), 'Test':list('PQRSTM')})
```

I want to check if the values of df2['Type'] is present in df1['Type'] and if yes, then replace the corresponding value in df1['Set'] with the corresponding value from df2. So, the final df1 should like this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABCD'), 'Set':list('PQRS')})
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Merge:

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABCD'), 'Set':list('ZZXY')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABCDEF'), 'Test':list('PQRSTM')})

df1= pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on = 'Type', right_on = 'Type', how ='left').drop('Set', axis =1)

print(df1)
```